# On some credits orders, status = disputed, can't change to "settled" or "refunded" using Update Order API

Tags: facebook, payment, credits

We have received disputes on a few Facebook Credits payments, and are trying to settle/refund them.

We've tried the following:

As outlined in the Dispute Resolution section of the credits API, by calling the /[order id] API with the order-id, status=settled, and specify the reason as the comment in the params. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/#disputeresolution

ex. https://graph.facebook.com/[order_id]?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&status=settled&message=solved&params={%27comment%27=%27Settled%20with%20user%27}

(replacing order_id with the 13 character numerical order ID of the order in question, and ACCESS_TOKEN with our actual access token)

But we have as yet been unable to change the status of a disputed order_id.

Has anyone been able to successfully either settle or refund a disputed payment yet? Is there anything wrong with the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me with double curly brackets around the comment argument, also note the => instead of =

&params=**{**{'comment' **=>** 'Settled with user'}**}**